# merge json data from the same array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I have one json array like this:

```
    var arr1 = [
      {id : 1, branchId : 1, branchDetail : "yes"}, 
      {id : 1, branchId : 2, branchDetail : "no"}, 
      {id : 2, branchId : 1, branchDetail : "yes"}
    ];
```

I want to merge the data if they have the same id, and create another data to handle merging. Like for example like this one:

```
    var finalArr = [
        {id : 1, 
         branch : [
            {branchId:1, branchDetail:"yes" },
            {branchId : 2, branchDetail : "no"}
         ]
        }, 
        {id : 2, 
         branch : [
            {branchId : 1, branchDetail : "yes"}
         ]
        }
    ];
```

I think $.extend() is not the right way because it only overwrites the last supplied value in the key.

Is it better to handle on the display or before the data displays?

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with reduce, map, and Object.keys:

```
var arr1 = [
   {id : 1, branchId : 1, branchDetail : "yes"}, 
   {id : 1, branchId : 2, branchDetail : "no"}, 
   {id : 2, branchId : 1, branchDetail : "yes"}
 ];


var object = arr1.reduce(function(memo, item){
  // initialise item
  (memo[item.id] = memo[item.id] || {id: item.id, branch: []})

  // add the branch to it
  .branch.push({
      branchId: item.branchId, branchDetail: item.branchDetail
  });

  return memo;
},{})

var finalArray = Object.keys(object)
  .map(function(k){
    return object[k]
  })

console.log(finalArray);
```

Comment: So if I have other keys aside from id, I will insert them one by one on this part? `(memo[item.id] = memo[item.id] || {id: item.id, otherKey1 : otherValue1, otherKey2 : otherValue2, ... , otherKeyN : otherValueN, branch: []})` ? Or there is another way?

Comment: Okay, by that adding other keys, I now use $.extend(). `$.extend( memo[item.id], item);`

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Array.prototype.forEach()`

```js
    var arr1 = [{
      id: 1,
      branchId: 1,
      branchDetail: "yes"
    }, {
      id: 1,
      branchId: 2,
      branchDetail: "no"
    }, {
      id: 2,
      branchId: 1,
      branchDetail: "yes"
    }];

    var finalArr = [{
      id: 1,
      branch: []
    }, {
      id: 2,
      branch: []
    }];

    arr1.forEach(function(a, b, array) {
      [a]
      .forEach(function(val, key) {
        finalArr.forEach(function(obj, k) {
          if (obj.id === val.id) {
            obj.branch.push({
              branchId: val.branchId,
              branchDetail: val.branchDetail
            })
          }
        })
      })
    });

    $("pre").text(JSON.stringify(finalArr, null, 2));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<pre></pre>
```